# Something's wrong with my Ubuntu, apt-get upgrade stopped working

Tags: ubuntu

So I was trying to install gpac from source (a big mistake) and in the process I broke my Ubuntu machine. I can do sudo apt-get update but when I do sudo apt-get upgrade, I get this error:

```
richard@richard-desktop:~/projects/sdp-encode-node$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 freeglut3-dev : Depends: freeglut3 (= 2.6.0-0ubuntu2) but 2.6.0-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
richard@richard-desktop:~/projects/sdp-encode-node$
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try running `apt-get -f install`, like the message suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the key part of that error message is this:

```
freeglut3-dev : Depends: freeglut3
```

You could try installing `freeglut3` or, if you don't need `freeglut3-dev`, try removing that.

Either way, you may need `-f` to force it to work rather than complaining about unmet dependencies:

```
apt-get -f install freeglut3
```

Or

```
apt-get -f remove freeglut3-dev
```